# Question on adjoint functors

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, adjoint-functors

Can someone provide me an enlightenment on the following three statements?
(I stumbled on them at the part dealing injective modules in a text of homological algebra.)

> 1) Let $F \dashv G \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is a pair of adjoint functors and $F$ preserves monomorphisms. Then $G$ preserves injectives.
>
> 2) A left adjoint preserves epimorphisms.
>
> 3) A right adjoint preserves monomorphisms.

Seeing that the text gives no clues for the proofs, they must make an easy exercise.
But I cannot make out how to show them.

Comment: These are abelian categories?

Comment: @Bruno Joyal  No. The text treats abelian categories after setting up generalities on homology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General advice when dealing with this sort of exercise: Definitions, definitions, definitions. Always go back to the definitions. Write down explicitly what you want to prove, and in 95% of cases the proof will almost write itself down for you.

---

For example for question #1: I will write down everything very formally. In a normal proof everything would be condensed in a few lines (cf. Hanno's answer), but hopefully this will help you in finding how to reason.

What is an injective? It's an object $I$ such that if for every morphism $f : A \to I$ and every *monomorphism* (notice how $F$ conveniently preserves *monomorphisms*?) $g : A \to B$, there exists a morphism $h : B \to I$ such that $h \circ g = f$ (write down the commutative diagram).

Now you want to show that if

- **Data 1**: $I \in \mathcal{D}$ is injective,

then $G(I) \in \mathcal{C}$ is injective. So by *definition* you take

- **Data 2**: any morphism $f : A \to G(I)$, and
- **Data 3**: any monomorphism $g : A \to B$,

and you look for some $h : B \to G(I)$ that makes the diagram commute.

Now you only have two hypotheses:

- **Hyp 4**: $F \dashv G$,
- **Hyp 5**: $F$ preserves monomorphisms.

There's only one monomorphism in this story, so apply your **Hyp 5** to it:

- **Fact 6**: $F(g) : F(A) \to F(B)$ is a monomorphism.

You know that $I$ is injective. By **Hyp 4**, you've got a morphism $\tilde{f} : F(A) \to I$ naturally associated to $f$. By taking **Fact 6** into account, and the **Data 1** that $I$ is injective, you find that

- **Fact 7**: there exists a morphism $\phi : F(B) \to I$ such that $\phi \circ F(g) = \tilde{f}$.

Now you apply **Hyp 4** again and you find a morphism $h = \bar\phi : B \to G(I)$. Since the adjunction $F \dashv G$ is **natural**, you finally find that $h \circ g = f$. Qed.

---

Now if you follow the same pattern of reasoning you should find the answers to question 2 and 3.

Comment: (+1) This is a really lovely unpacking of the problem-solving process involved: know what ingredients you have at your disposal, and if you get stuck, check if you've actually used all your ingredients.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will track down the reasoning flow until I am convinced that I have understood.

Answer (score 6):

*Hint for (1):* Note that an object $I\in{\mathscr D}$ is injective if and only if ${\mathscr D}(-,I): {\mathscr D}^{\text{op}}\to\textsf{Set}$ preserves epimorphisms (i.e., turns monomorphisms in ${\mathscr D}$ into surjective maps of sets) - and analogously for objects of ${\mathscr C}$. Now suppose $X\in{\mathscr D}$ is injective & that ${\mathscr F}$ preserves monomorphisms and check that by adjointness of ${\mathscr F}$ and ${\mathscr G}$ the functor ${\mathscr C}(-,{\mathscr G}X)$ also maps monomorphisms in ${\mathscr C}$ to epimorphisms.

Parts (2) and (3) are similar, noting that a morphism $f: X\to Y$ in ${\mathscr C}$ is, say, an epimorphism if and only if for all $Z\in{\mathscr C}$ the induced map of sets ${\mathscr C}(f,Z): {\mathscr C}(Y,Z)\to{\mathscr C}(X,Z)$ is injective, i.e. a monomorphism in $\textsf{Set}$. Similar for monomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks! I will track down your hint together with the detail account by Najib Idrissi.

Answer (score 1):

Although the previous answers contain hints how to prove  2) and 3), it seems desirable to give a complete proof.

We only prove 2), the proof of 3) is dual.

Let $F : \mathcal C  \to \mathcal D$ be a left adjoint to some functor $G : \mathcal D  \to \mathcal C$. This means that there is a natural bijection
$$\tau_{X,Y} : \mathcal D(F(X),Y) \to \mathcal C(X,G(Y)), X \in  ob(\mathcal C), Y \in  ob(\mathcal D) . $$

Let $e : Z \to X$ be an epimorphism in $\mathcal C$. We have to show that $F(e) : F(Z) \to F(X)$ is an epimorphism in $\mathcal D$ which means that if  $f_0, f_1 : F(X) \to Y$ are two morphisms in $\mathcal D$ such that $f_0 \circ F(e) = f_1 \circ F(e)$, then $f_0 = f_1$.

Consider the following commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathcal D(F(X),Y) @>{\tau_{X,Y}}>> \mathcal C(X,G(Y)) \\
@V{F(e)^*}VV @VV{e^*}V \\
\mathcal D(F(Z),Y) @>>{\tau_{Z,Y}}> \mathcal C(Z,G(Y))
\end{CD}

We are given $f_0, f_1 \in \mathcal D(F(X),Y)$ such that $F(e)^*(f_0) = f_0 \circ F(e) = f_1 \circ F(e) = F(e)^*(f_1)$. We conclude
$$\tau_{X,Y}(f_0)\circ e = e^*(\tau_{Z,Y}(f_0)) = \tau_{Z,Y}(F(e)^*(f_0)) = \\ \tau_{Z,Y}(F(e)^*(f_1)) = e^*(\tau_{Z,Y}(f_1)) = \tau_{X,Y}(f_1)\circ e .$$
Thus $\tau_{X,Y}(f_0) = \tau_{X,Y}(f_1)$ because $e$ is an epimorphism. Hence $f_0 = f_1$ because $\tau_{X,Y}$ is a bijection.

A nice corollary is this:

A necessary condition for $F : \mathcal C  \to \mathcal D$ having a right adjoint is that $F$ preserves epimorphisms.

Comment: Thank you very much,, indeed.   Nine years have passed since I asked the question, but your enlightenment is still helpful.